# Using batch, how would you iterate through an array that you don't know how many values it may contain to run a function on each individual variable

Tags: arrays, batch-file, variables, ffmpeg, batch-processing

I have a batch file creating an array of variables it gets from a textfile, as follows:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=9 delims= " %%a in (%findfile%) do set "_%%a=yes"
set count = 0
for /f "tokens=1* delims==#" %%b in ('set _') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set x=%%b
    set location[!count!]=!x:~1!
)
set %location%
```

I'm trying to get each variable from the array to be looped into a function individually, but have no idea how to do it!!

The ***location*** array storing all the variables has to be called into a for loop and the function I'm trying to get it to loop into is an FFMPEG function:

```
for %%i in (%location%\*.mp4) do (if not exist "%%~ni\" MD "%%~ni"

    ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vframes 1 -f image2 -start_number 0 
    "%%~ni\%%~ni_Summary_%%3d.jpeg"

)
```

All HELP would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `set count = 0` should be `set /a count = 0`. As it stands, you are setting a variable called count*space* to *space*0. It works by failing to fail. `count` is not defined, hence `set /a count+=1` counts correctly. No reason why you can't use `set /a count+=1&set "location[!count!]=%%a"` in the first loop to generate and count the `location` array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set %location%` should be `set location`. It is supposed to show all variables, that start with `location`.
There is no such thing as a (real) array, it's just a bunch of variables. So you can't addres the whole collection as `%location%`.
That said: you have the number of variables in `%count%`, so you can happily use a `for /L`:

```
@echo off 
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM get locations from textfile:
for /f "tokens=9" %%a in (file.txt) do set "_%%a=yes"

REM translate into proper variables:
set count=0
for /f "tokens=1* delims==#" %%a in ('set _') do (
  set /a count+=1
  set x=%%a
  set _var[!count!]=!x:~1!
)

REM build the new bat file:
(for /l %%i in (1 1 %count%) do (
  for %%a in ("!_var[%%i]!\*.mp4") do (
    ECHO ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vframes 1 -f image2 -start_number 0 "%%~na\%%~na_Summary_%%3d.jpeg"
  )
))>new.bat

type new.bat
```

Comment: whats the >new.bat about? ---
is going to create a new batch file for each location that is called in?

Comment: no, it's creating ONE batchfile, including ALL `ffmpeg` commands. (note the additional pair of parantheses around the whole `for` loop)

Answer (score 0):

As you already has the count of elements, you can use a FOR /L loop.

```
FOR /L %%n in (1 1 %count%) DO (
  set "content=!location[%%n]!"
  call :subFunc content
)
...

:subFunc
set "var=!%1!"
echo Process: !var!
```

Comment: And do i do this outside of the FFMPEG FOR loop or put it within?

Comment: Aack! Not to be using `tmp` as a variable-name, please! It's a predefined variable (=`temp`)